# RSKeyMgmt -r unable to remove installtion ID

Tags: reporting-services

I have backed up databases on one `2005 SQL Server` and have restored those databases on a second `2005 SQL Server`. I am currently trying to remove the new server's OLD key instance ID using the `Reporting Services Key Manager` (`RSKeyMgmt -r`).

Prior to running the removal command the list of the current instances shows the new server's OLD instance ID as well as the NEW instance ID from the first SQL Server. Executing the `RSKeyMgmt -r` command results in:

> The command completed successfully

However, when I recheck the listing of current instance IDs I see both the OLD and NEW instance IDs. In addition, when I check the Application Event Viewer I see an error:

> Report Server Windows Service (MSSQLSERVER) has not been granted access to the catalog content

Does anyone know why I would be getting the above application error?

Or...does anyone know what I would need to do to give access to the catalog to the Report Server Window Service?

The first SQL Server where the databases were backed up is an Enterprise edition SQL Server and the second SQL Server where the databases were restored is `Standard edition`. Could this be the cause of the problem? Is there a way to make this backup and restore migration work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the original/old TFS environment did not have any custom reports set up and encryption for the report server was unnecessary. So I ended up just Deleting the encryption keys. This allowed me to bypass the problem.